# Android: Support ActionBar icons messed up (Galaxy S2 Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm having an issue with ActionBar icons being drawn incorrectly on Galaxy S2 running JB and Android Support Library v13.

It works fine on Galaxy S3, Galaxy S4 running the same OS so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Galaxy S2 output (Android 4.1.2 model number GT-I9100):

[image]

Galaxy S3 output:

[image]

Nexus 4 output:

[image]

Galaxy S4 output:

[image]

HTC One M8 output:

[image]

Xperia Z output:

[image]

Is this a bug with the Galaxy S2? Is it possible to even fix this?

Comment: I doubt that, I used to develop on an S2 and never saw this -- a mistake on the resource files is a far more likely explanation . Nexus 4, S3, S4, HTC One and XPeria Z are all `xhdpi` or `xxhdpi`, while S2 is `hdpi` -- is it possible that you just have drawables of the wrong size for that bucket? Remember you have to follow the 2:3:4:6:8 ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this happened because I forgot to add hdpi resources for the S2. Adding the hdpi resources fixed the problem.

Comment: Sorry about intervening.. but it seems like user `matiash's` comment set you on the right path. If possible, ask them to post an answer for you to accept. Please ignore this comment if their answer was not how you solved this problem. :)

Comment: @Mrinali It was just a suggestion, so i didn't think to post it as an answer... It would be a shame to let the bounty rep go to waste, but oh well. :/

Comment: try to use nine patch image refer this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and if you are using drawable  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html